Is it possible to control the site title in Google search results?
Is it possible to control the indexed site title in Google search results?
I would like to clarify that I am not referring to the contents of the <title> tag, but rather, the site title that appears in the eyebrow content above the title tag, along with the URL. The title I'm looking to target is circled in red here:

Is there any metadata that can target this? I've tried editing the <title> tag, Opengraph tags, author meta, Twitter meta, all of it.

Yes, you can influence the site title that appears in Google search results, but you can't fully control it. Google generates this title based on several factors, including the content of your  tag, structured data, and the text on your page. However, there isn't any specific metadata that allows you to directly set this title. The best approach is to ensure your site’s name and relevant keywords are consistently used throughout your site, and to use structured data to help Google understand how to display your site in search results.

I generally think that Google is populating that by the company/site name. You could potentially use schema to influence it. You could start by looking at Organization schema and drill down the various child ones (LocalBusiness, OnlineBusiness, etc.)
I suspect what you put in the name or legalName fields would influence what shows in the SERP.
Schema.org has a lot of good examples at the bottom of the page and they also have a markup validator.
Of course Google ultimately reserves the right to display whatever they think should be there so don't be surprised if they show something different even after implementing schema.
